# How reload/update parts of my page without reloading the entire page

Tags: reactjs, laravel, vue.js

I am working on a project where I want to refresh parts of the page instead of refreshing the entier page itself.

For example, my master layout contains the following items,

- Navbar (Home, Details, Contact Us)
- Footer

And the body will refresh when I click on either of the Menus on the Navbar or links in the Footer without refresing the entire page.

After doing some research I found out that this can be done using Ajax, VueJS or ReactJs.

Now, my question is which one would be a better solution to implement such feature.

Comment: What do you actually mean by hot reloading in Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are pretty much confused here. I would suggest you to describe what do you want to achieve because hot reloading does not make any sense in Laravel i.e PHP as it is an interpreted language and does not need compilation you change the code and that's it you are ready to test it. Also Laravel provides you a framework to deal with databases and its blade engine can provide you UI i.e web pages whereas Flutter is more centric towards Mobile Application development nonetheless they have provided support for web but they still do not recommend to use it in product as it is only a technical preview.

Answer (score 1):

@kushagra, hot reloading makes complete sense in Laravel, because you have to load vue.js components which must be compiled after each alteration regardless of how minimal, in order for the changes to be displayed on screen.

Also, here for a related issue:
npm run hot script compiles resources "successfully" but doesn't actual make the changes display on screen for me.

Vue.js is your best bet, but jquery ajax will get the job done as well.